# How to resolve a circular dependency in nest js?

Tags: express, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have my app.module that imports UserModule and AuthModule.

```
@Module({
  imports: [UserModule, AuthModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is how my AuthModule looks:

```
@Module({
  imports: [forwardRef(() => UserModule)],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, UserService],
  exports: [AuthModule],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

And UserModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

I inject userService in AuthService. If i delete AuthModule from AppModule, the dependency disapears, so, the problem is maybe somewhere there.

Comment: If you're injecting `UserService` in `AuthService` why did you not export it? `exports: [UserService]` (in `UserModule`)

Comment: @MicaelLevi, yeah, I solved it by trying random combination of imports and exports. Thank you, now i know how and why it works.

Comment: @Helios could you please provide your final solution that made it works?

Answer (score 3):

If you think there shouldn't be any circular dependency issue because you have follow the concept of SOLID... then you are right.. there should not be any circular dependency issue UNLESS your imports are wrong..

typescript gives facility of absolute path but always use relative path while importing

Wrong Way

```
import {Category} from '/src/categories';
```

Right Way

```
import {Category} from '../categories';
```

do this in your entire project your circular dependency will be resolved

Answer (score 2):

First of all, configure the user module and auth module so that they can refer to each other.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => UserModule),
  ],
  exports: [AuthService],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}

@Module({
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => AuthModule),
  ],
  exports: [UserService],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

In this situation, two different services that perform dependency injection must also be configured so that cross-references are possible.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => AuthService))
  )
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => UserService))
  )
}
```

Please try and comment if it doesn't work.

Comment: I already solved my problem, but i tried this approach and it did not work. The problem is maybe that these modules are also imported in AppModule.

Answer (score 0):

If you strongly believe that circular dependency is a false positive, check that if you happen to have a JSON file with the same name as a `.ts` file